# Write SQL data into Memory rather than table

Tags: sql, sql-server, logging, clr

I have a SQL DB where log steps in a large number of SPs are constantly writing hundreds of lines into a error log table and using up resources on the server. One solution suggested was to write the log into memory and once the log count was over 1000 rows then bulk insert this into the log table rather than constantly writing the individual lines. I have had using CLR mentioned - can anyone point me in the right direction as to how to use this? does the above sound feasible?

Comment: So, what is thew actual question? How to use an on memory structure?

Comment: How can u use bulk insert if logs are from different stored procedures

Comment: the suggestion was to buffer all the logs into memory and once there was a critcal amount in there they get bulk inserted into a table - the idea is rather than constantly writing all the time as they do now we load them up and then send in batches.

Answer (score 0):

> I have a SQL DB where log steps in a large number of SPs are
>   constantly writing hundreds of lines into a error log table and using
>   up resources on the server. One solution suggested was **to write the
>   log into memory** and once the log count was over 1000 rows then bulk
>   insert this into the log table

You are already writing to a memory. When you write something to a table, you NEVER wtire to a disk. All operations are made in memory. And only at some moments SQL Server will flush dirty(modified) pages to disk. These moments are checkponts:

> For performance reasons, the Database Engine performs modifications to
>   database pages **in memory—in the buffer cache**—and does not write these
>   pages to disk after every change. Rather, the Database Engine
>   periodically issues a checkpoint on each database. A checkpoint writes
>   the current in-memory modified pages (known as dirty pages) and
>   transaction log information from memory to disk and, also, records
>   information about the transaction log.

Link: [Database Checkpoints (SQL Server)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/logs/database-checkpoints-sql-server)

Comment: thanks for reply - so do you think this is possible - let me try explain it better - we have a load of SPs writing to an Activity table key steps within each SP - e.g. 'process new clients' plus date and time - this results in thousands of rows being written and performance issues on server - can we use Checkpoints to flag this data and configure the server or trigger and SP to bulk insert this data to the Activity table when a critical mass of data is reached, therefore storing the data up i memory rather than constantly writing to the table - thanks

Comment: You are looking in a wrong direction. Your problem is NOT that server writes to disk, I repeat it, all your inserts are performing in memory. You should check what is your real bottleneck, for example, use sys.dm_os_waiting_tasks to find out what your waits are